# NLog ASP.Net viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, nlog

I am using nLog in a large financial application, but frequently need to bring up the logs of the last hour while the software is running and filter on specific loggers/levels. I want to log everything to SQL, and use an asp.net viewer. Do any such project exist? Are there some good example sites for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NLogViewer](https://github.com/lytri/NLogViewer)

Answer (score 0):

Also, [Sentinel](http://sentinel.codeplex.com/) (free, open source on codeplex) is another option.

Comment: not an asp.net viewer - op: "and use an asp.net viewer"